# how to check if a string contains any value (no matter symbol or any thing) in js?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a webpage where the user is asked to enter his name, and his name is stored in his browser. If he/she opens the same page they should be greeted with the name they entered while they were asked before. I tried

```js
var x; //x is undefined to check if it contains value 
function name() {
    x = prompt("Input your name");
}

function save() {
    localStorage.setItem('name', x); //saving name in local storage that is in x variable
    let myName = localStorage.getItem('name'); //getting the item name
}
if (x == undefined) { // if x doesn't contains value it ask to enter name 
    name();
} else {
    save(); // if there is 
    document.write(x)
}
document.write(names)
```

What am I doing incorrectly?

Comment: If you do not care about what the string actually contains, you can simply check that is length is greater than 0 (that is to say, it contains at least one character): `x.length > 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = localStorage.getItem('name');
if (!name) {
  name = prompt("Input your name");
  localStorage.setItem('name', name);
}
document.write(name);
```

Answer (score 2):

The logic should really be,

1. get value from localStorage
2. if the localStorage was empty ask for name and save it to localStorage
3. show name

(*additionally, it is better to avoid using `document.write`*)

In your code, you never check what is stored in the localStorage, before prompting for the name.

```js
var name = restoreName();

function restoreName() {
  return localStorage.getItem('name');
}

function askName() {
  return prompt("Input your name");
}

function saveName(providedName) {
  //saving name in local storage that is in x variable
  localStorage.setItem('name', providedName || '');
}

if (!name) { // if x doesn't contains value it ask to enter name 
  name = askName();
  saveName(name);
}

alert(`Hello ${name}`);
```

Comment: but that created an error i was unable to ask for the name it doesn't uses the askName (); function insted it shows Hello null

Comment: that would happen because if you click `cancel` on the prompt it will return null, and if you try to set the localStorage item to `null` it will store `"null"` as a string. I updated the `saveName` function to handle that.

Answer (score 1):

you can just use

```
if (!x)
```

this will cover null or empty string